# dax handling summary values in a matrix report

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

Source data columns are Store, Product, StoreSales, and ProductSales

StoreSales has duplicate values, even across different Stores.

Looking for a dax measure to handle StoreSales as described in the image.

This is the closest so far, but doesn't account for duplicates between stores.

Store Sales:= 
sumx(DISTINCT(_Sales[StoreSales), _Sales[StoreSales])

[screenshot of source and pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15r3l.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, this formula should give you the desired result:

```
Desired Result for Store Sales = 
IF(ISFILTERED(_Sales[Store]), SUM(_Store[Store Sales]))
```

However, I recommend to revisit your data model design. It's conceptually incorrect (you are mixing detailed data with the summary of the same data), and you will have serious problems with DAX. A better way to structure your data:

- Remove column "Store Sales". It's redundant and does not fit the data level of detail.
- Rename column "Product Sales" into "Sale Amount". It's just sale amount, without any qualifiers.
- Create a measure "Total Sales" = SUM(_Sales[Sale Amount]). It will correctly calculate total sales both on product and store levels.

If you need a special measure for store sales, use SUMX:

```
Store-level sales = SUMX (VALUES(_Sales[Store]), [Total Sales])
```

And if you need to show product contributions to store sales:

```
Product Contribution = `DIVIDE([Total Sales], [Store-Level Sales])
```